# Confusion regarding isometric isomorphisms

Tags: functional-analysis

I am having some confusion surrounding isometric isomorphisms in Functional Analysis. To my knowledge, $\phi$ is an **isometric isomorphism** if

1. $\phi$ is bijective and $\phi^{-1}$ is continuous
2. $\phi^{-1}$ is an isometry.

Why is it that in some examples I find of this, the continuity of $\phi^{-1}$ is not shown? Is it the case that if $\phi$ is continuous and bijective, than $\phi^{-1}$ is continuous, and this is why it is not shown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isometries are continuous. The inverse of an isometry is an isometry. Once you show your map is an isometry then it follows that it must be continuous!

Comment: Right, that makes sense then. Thank you.